# Accessing custom URL scheme data from an iFrame

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, url-scheme

If I have an iFrame that's trying to launch a custom URL scheme (e.g. `twitter://user?data=value`), Chrome will throw an error in the console:

`Failed to launch 'twitter://user?data=value' because the scheme does not have a registered handler`

I need to access that URL, without taking any actions (like launching Twitter, for example). If the console is displaying this error information, that must mean the client has access to the URL and data.

Is there a way to intercept these errors and deal with the URL myself?

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to launch a custom URL" and " accessing custom URL data"?  The error is irrelevant  since it's only confirming that `twitter:` is not an internet protocol.

Comment: On a mobile device, launching twitter://something will open a deep link to the twitter app. I'm asking if I can access this information from an iframe solely in a browser